# XML to HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have this code from W3School website. If I run from the W3School editor, it works fine. If I copy the same code on to my desktop nothing happens. I have ensure the XML and the HTML file both are in the same folder. When I try to open the HTML File I don't even see the button which is there in the script below.

Can anyone help?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      myFunction(xmlhttp);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<CATALOG>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>

<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1985</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>

<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1988</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>

<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1982</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>

<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>

<YEAR>1990</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Eros</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>

<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1997</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>One night only</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>

<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1998</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.10</PRICE>

<YEAR>1973</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.50</PRICE>

<YEAR>1990</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>

<PRICE>10.80</PRICE>

<YEAR>1996</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.70</PRICE>

<YEAR>1987</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>

<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1995</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>

<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>

<YEAR>1999</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.70</PRICE>

<YEAR>1995</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>

<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1997</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>

<YEAR>1971</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>

<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1996</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1990</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Stop</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1988</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>

<ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>

<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1987</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1983</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>

<PRICE>7.80</PRICE>

<YEAR>1983</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>

<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1991</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>

<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>

<YEAR>1987</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>

<PRICE>7.20</PRICE>

<YEAR>1985</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Red</TITLE>

<ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>London</COMPANY>

<PRICE>7.80</PRICE>

<YEAR>1987</YEAR>

</CD>


-<CD>

<TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>

<ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>

<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>

<COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>

<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>

<YEAR>1987</YEAR>

</CD>

</CATALOG>
```

Comment: You need to remove the dashes/minus signs from the XML

Comment: @user2182349, the dashes are for collapsing the XML, it got copied from XML, but there are no dashes in the notepad where XML file is stored.

Comment: Running off the file system has different rules than running it on a webserver. Install a local webserver and run the files that way. Look at the browser's console for JavaScript error messages.

Comment: As @epascarello mentioned - because the page has Ajax, it needs to request the XML from a web server.

Comment: Well technically you can change the config options or start it up with file access flags and it will work, but better to develop the smart way with a local server.